How can Ketephys have the Moon Subdomain without the Darkness Domain?
So in Ketephys's entry in Inner Sea Gods he clearly is listed as having the Moon subdomain but does not have the Darkness Domain. How exactly would taking this subdomain work?

You do know the moon doesn’t only come out at night?

Ketephys is a maneater? /j

@DaleM This is a mechanics question. I've never seen an entry for a god where a Subdomain was included and the parent Domain wasn't. Since Ketephys doesn't grant the Darkness domain does this mean that you don't get the base spells of darkness and only the replacement spells listed under the moon subdomain?

In "Inner Sea Gods" the dirty has a different set of domains, but I understand this is not the question.

@Flywheel25a Ketephys's entry in inner sea gods is what I was referencing, specifically the table in the appendix on pages 322/323. It lists his domains as Animal, Chaos, Good, Plant, Weather and his subdomains as Azata, Feather, Fur, Growth, Moon, Seasons.

The only text I was able to find for eligibility was from the introduction of subdomains in the Advanced Player's Guide:

Each subdomain replaces a granted power and a number of spells in the
domain's granted spell list. A cleric who chooses a subdomain must
have access to both the domain and its subdomain from her deity. If a
cleric selects a subdomain, she cannot select its associated domain as
her other domain choice (in effect, the subdomain replaces its
associated domain). Subdomains are treated as equivalent to their
associated domain for any effect or prerequisite based on domains. If
a subdomain has two associated domains, the cleric can only select the
subdomain for one of her domains. Subdomains can be selected by Druids
(except the metal subdomain) and inquisitors (if their deity allows
it).

This would seem to imply that a deity that provides a subdomain without the main domain doesn't actually do anything, since eligibility checks for both the base and the subdomain. To my knowledge, the APG was written before there were any published deities that did this, so it is reasonable to declare that it was inadequately future-proofed and that an orphaned subdomian should do something.
Since we've already entered common sense rulings, an orphan subdomain should provide the non-replaced abilities of the parent domain because otherwise it would be missing significant amounts of content. I was not expecting to find an example of this being officially used. Most openly available sources of statblocks with cleric levels stick to the core deities, who don't have any orphaned subdomains. However, it happens that this situation comes up in one of the official adventure paths that I happen to have on hand. AP #90, The Divinity Drive, features a cleric of a deity that grants the Stars subdomain without the parent Void domain, who has also taken Stars as one of their domain choices. Their statblock (pages 56-57) includes both the save bonus vs mind-affecting and the domain spell planar binding alongside abilities specific to Stars.
Another point in favour of allowing access to the base domain spells is the Acolyte of Apocrypha trait from Divine Anthology. It adds new subdomains onto existing deities even if they don't correspond to the base domains that deity offers. Here, using the parent domain spells is explicitly spelled out, though a restrictive reading could interpret that as applying only to subdomains made available by this trait:

In some cases, you can select a subdomain associated with a deity despite that deity not offering the associated domain—these exceptions are noted with an asterisk (*), and you gain domain powers and domain spells from the associated domain as usual, even though your deity normally doesn’t grant access to that domain.


Thanks, I think that's as close to definitive as we're going to get.
